# Configuring Weather Agent with API Key and Location

Tags: volttron

Following the documentation: http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/4.1/core_services/service_agents/weather/WeatherAgentInstallation.html#configuring-and-launching-the-weather-agent

the steps worked smoothly until the: **Configuring Weather Agent with API Key and Location**

```
$ nano services/core/weather/settings.py
```

first this message shown after typing the above script:

```
 [ Directory 'services/core/weather' does not exist ]
```

even I went to the directory and typed: `ls` it shows the directory and files exist.

> **init**.py  settings.py  weatheragent.py

After inserting the key value from weather underground, I attempted to save the modified file (settings.py) using (ctrl+x = exit)

first this message shown after trying to exit :

> Save modified buffer (ANSWERING "No" WILL DESTROY CHANGES) ?
>    Y Yes
>    N No
>             ^C Cancel

I typed Y , and then

> File Name to Write: services/core/weather/settings.py

I hit enter

I got the error message :

```
[ Error writing services/core/weather/settings.py: No such file or directory ]
```

as shown in the link 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew2jT.png

Ubuntu : 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!! this is the directoy:

```
nano /home/user_name/volttron/services/core/WeatherAgent/weather/settings.py
```